# How to use simple-menu in django?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

```
I have below html code for submenu. Now i have to integrate with my django application.
```

HTML Code :

```
<nav class="main-navigation" data-height="auto" data-size="6px" data-distance="0" data-rail-visible="true" data-wheel-step="10">
                    <p class="nav-title">MENU</p>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <!-- dashboard -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="a.html">
                                <i class="ti-home"></i>
                                <span>Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;">
                                <i class="toggle-accordion"></i>
                                <i class="ti-support"></i>
                                <span>Category1</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="SubCategory1.html">
                                        <span>Sub Category1</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="SubCategory2.html">
                                        <span>Sub Category2</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;">
                                <i class="toggle-accordion"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                                <span>Category2</span> 
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="SubCategory7.html">
                                        <span>SubCategory7</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                </nav>
```

I have used simple-menu module for that.
but i don't understand how to apply bootstarp class in simple menu which are in below code.
For this submenu i have to use simple-submenu ?
i have try simple-menu Code is below.

```
<nav class="main-navigation" data-height="auto" data-size="6px" data-distance="0" data-rail-visible="true" data-wheel-step="10">
                    <p class="nav-title">MENU</p>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        {% for item in menu%}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ item.url }}">
                                <i class="ti-home"></i>
                                <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                {% for child in item.children%}
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ item.url }}">
                                        <span>{{ child.title }}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- /ui -->
                </nav>
```

On above code how to apply different classes in for loop for particular html tag ?

Comment: Can you be more precise as to which **HTML** tag you want to assign the classes to?

Comment: In my HTml code <i> tag has applied some classe

Comment: Do you have a set of those classes in an array that you are sending from your view or you want it generated randomly? Both is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use randomly generated classes or use Django's [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) tag.

**Using randomly generated classes**:

```
{% for item in menu%}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">
            <i class="ti-home-{{forloop.counter}}"></i>
            <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
...
```

**Using cycle tag**:

```
{% for item in menu%}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">
            <i class="{% cycle "ti-home-1" "ti-home-2" "ti-home-3" "ti-home-end"%}"></i>
            <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
...
```

Comment: yes , it may be usefull , but  if there are more tags which are same but different classes in that case how to apply cycle tag ? Beacase during first encounter how to produce two or more argument ?                       Ex: <i class="toggle-accordion"></i>    
       <i class="ti-support"></i>                                                                                        <i class="ti-home"></i>

Comment: You add them to the list of your classes in `cycle` tag thusly: `<i class="{% cycle "toggle-accordion" "ti-support" "ti-home" "and-so-on"%}"></i>` or if you want to have access the current class and do a thing with it you can pass in `as` as in `<i class="{% cycle "toggle-accordion" "ti-support" "ti-home" "and-so-on" as myclass %}"></i>`

Comment: on aboce question <ul> tag have three  <li> tags. each <li> tags has num of different classe. so during first iterate aplly first class. during 2nd itereate apply 2nd class but not apply 3rd calss

Comment: Check your code very well and ensure `cycle` tag has **three** classes and don't also forget to read the documentation as provided in the answer above.

Comment: Yes, but on every iterate only one class applied but how to applied multiple classes on every iterate